# passing event object in function inside iframe IE8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I'm loading an .htm file dynamically inside an iframe ( the .htm is in my domain ) like this:

```
el.innerHTML = "<iframe id='frmBook' onload='on_load()' src='blabla.htm'";
```

my on_load is like this:

```
function on_load() {

    document.getElementById("frmBook").contentWindow.document.body.ondblclick = function(event) {
        var oTextRange;
        if (!document.selection) {
            oTextRange = window.getSelection();
            if (oTextRange.rangeCount > 0) oTextRange.collapseToStart();
        }
        getWord(event);
    }

    document.getElementById("frmBook").contentWindow.document.body.oncontextmenu = function(event) {
        showContextMenu(event);
        return false;
    }
}
```

now i need to pass the event object because it is used inside both getWord() and showContextMenu(). It is used in getWord() to get the e.target.id ( or e.srcElement ) and in showContextMenu() to use e.page.X. The trouble is, IE8 does not recognize ( undefined ) the event object so it does not get passed. is there any way to pass the event object for IE8?

thanks in advance!

Answer (score -1):

First of all, assign your ifram string this way:

```
el.innerHTML = '<iframe id="frmBook" onload="on_load()" src="blabla.htm"></iframe>';
```

Otherwise it can not function.

Then, try to define variables with **var**, this way you prevent its content becomes *undefined*:

```
function on_load() {

    document.getElementById("frmBook").contentWindow.document.body.ondblclick = function(event) {
        var e = event;
        var oTextRange;
        if (!document.selection) {
            oTextRange = window.getSelection();
            if (oTextRange.rangeCount > 0) oTextRange.collapseToStart();
        }
        getWord(e);
    }

    document.getElementById("frmBook").contentWindow.document.body.oncontextmenu = function(event) {
        var e = event;
        showContextMenu(e);
        return false;
    }
}
```